# How to add a data connection in VS Express 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I open the visual studio express 2013 for windows and want to create a data connection it can't add and can't open the connection dialog windows and give me the following error :
" Unable to add data connection.
The IVsDataConnectionDialog could not be initialized. "
Please help me why and how can I add data connection to server explorer ?
Create new Sql server database  menu also is turn off and can't tap on it to create a sql server data connection and just the add data connection menu is turn on .
I reinstall vs express but it wasn't effective .
Please help me 
Thanks
Regards 
Raha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have team foundation server express 2013 installed.
http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-team-foundation-server-express